# what are the uses of by making strictfp class or method?

Tags: java, floating-point

Marking a class as strictfp means that any method code in the class will conform to the IEEE 754 standard rules for floating points.

What does this means? I really don't get it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Answer (score 3):

Some processors have capabilities for slightly more accurate arithmetic - e.g. 80 bits instead of 64 bits. Likewise on some processors it may be faster to use `double` arithmetic even where logically `float` arithmetic is used. So for example:

```
float foo(float x, float y)
{
    x = x * 1.2345f;
    y = y * 2.3456f;
    return x * y;
}
```

Here the intermediate operations could potentially be optimized to use 80-bit arithmetic throughout, only falling back to a 32-bit value when it's returned... even though the operation described in source code for each multiplication is theoretically a 32-bit multiplication.

When you use `strictfp`, you turn off those potential optimizations. It's rarely necessary, but it means that you're guaranteed that the exact same set of arithmetic operations - when given the exact same set of inputs - will give the exact same set of results regardless of implementation.

Comment: can you please give the example of strictfp  class?

Comment: @vijayk: I don't know what you mean. It's just a class modifier - the rest of the code in the class would look exactly the same as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Its all about **precision**.

The (IEEE 754) is a technical standard for floating-point computation (from wiki)

If you don't use strictfp, the JVM implementation is free to use extra precision where available.

For some applications, a programmer might need every platform to have precisely the same floating-point behaviour, even on platforms that could handle greater precision. However, if this level of precision is not necessary the VM does not use intermediates by default.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp